# USB Full install of ubuntu 18.04 can boot on one pc only

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I have used a pc without any internal hdd to install ubuntu on a 128gb usb stick.
I used an iso placed (using rufus) on a 4gb usb stick as an installer media.
Now whenever i try to boot the 128gb stick on the pc i used to install it in the first place it boots, but if I plug it in any other pc it wont boot. I tried to look up a solution online but everyhting i tried didn't work.

Comment: Is my understanding correct? You have one pc and two USB sticks. One USB stick is 4Gb with installer files in it. With this you have installed Ubuntu on 128GB Stick. You removed 4GB USB Stick from the pc and 128GB Stick is booting Ubuntu well on the same PC. Later you removed the 128GB USB Stick and kept in other systems.. But it's not booting rite?

Comment: In that case the configurations must match with pc to pc like boot mode.

Comment: Yeah you got it. Is there any way to get around the restriction of having the same hardware by doing some tweaking?

Comment: can you share the first pc mother board and the other pc mother boards models please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Full Install to USB - BIOS/UEFI**

Perhaps one computer uses UEFI and the older computer BIOS.
If you would like your USB drive to be able to boot from multiple computers, both BIOS and UEFI:

- Use **mkusb** to make a Live system on the Installer USB (2GB or larger).
- Use **mkusb** to make a Persistent system on the Target 128GB USB using default settings with ~25GB persistence, (remaining NTFS partition is used as Windows accessible data partition).

[image]

- Open GParted and delete sdx4, the ISO9660 partition and expand sdx5 into the recovered space, sdx being the device name of the Target drive.

[image]

- Unplug or remove HDD before proceeding further, (optional but recommended, highly recommended in UEFI mode).
- Boot Installer drive, select Try.
- Insert Target drive

Start Install Ubuntu...

- Select Something else.
- Select sdx5, (on the target drive), and click Change.

[image]

- Select Use as: ext4, Format and Mount point: /.

Don't touch any other partitions (unless adding a /home partition).

- Select sdx5 as **Device for boot loader installation**.
- Complete installation.
- Cut grub.cfg from sdx5/boot/grub and paste to sdx3/boot/grub, overwriting the existing grub.cfg file.
- Boot the target drive and run sudo update-grub to add all drives to boot menu.
- Do not install any propriety drivers, (ie Nvidia).

Comment: Ok going to try this as soon as I'm back from school, thanks!

Comment: @C.S.Cameron i have tried this answer. very nice. could you please explain the advantage of the point no 3 from bottom of your answer please. i.e Cut grub.cfg from sdx5/boot/grub

Comment: @PRATAP: When I was trying to develop this method, that was the first thing that worked for me. I only had to modify one partition in "Something else". It seemed to work pretty well so I stopped looking for a different procedure. I am willing to try any method you suggest.